# None of your email accounts could send to this recipient

Tags: exchange, outlook

One of my colleague keeps receiving this error often when sending.

"Your message did not reach some or all of the intended recipients.

```
  Subject:  ******
  Sent: 16/02/2012 11:49
```

The following recipient(s) cannot be reached:

```
  'EMAIL ADDRESS' on 16/02/2012 11:50
        None of your e-mail accounts could send to this recipient."
```

at the moment my colleague has to forward the email on to me as I don't 
have any problem with sending to these recipients. We thought it may be the recipients email address but as I can send the send it cancels out that theory.

We are both working off Exchange Server 2003 with MS Outlook 2010(colleague) and MS Outlook 2007 (me).

Does any one know what may be causing this email error?

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes find it useful to use TelNet and www.mxtoolbox.com to find out the status of the destination mail server, it at least gives you details on where the domain could be on a government black list....

Also check any web/mail filtering devices you end to see the mail have not got stuck while being checked. Common on Barracuda devices.

Answer (score 0):

I've come accross this a few times now, it's a bit of a strange one as there is no actual error code or number to research against. The issue appears to be a corrupt entry in the users autocomplete list.

To resolve the issue, get the user to delete the entry from the autocomplete list when they are composing a new email and then **type the email address in manually**.

As I said, a bit strange, but the steps I've given above seems to work.